# How to vertically stack bootstrap grid columns in variable heights?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a set of bootstrap grid columns with variable heights. At the moment due to the difference of height, they appear in as in the image on link.

http://postimg.org/image/uj0xn582b/

However What i require is to avoid the space between grids with small heights as shown by the arrows in the diagram and on the image on the link below.

http://postimg.org/image/c2m2813vf/

How can I achieve this using bootstrap.If it is not possible via bootstrap what other options do i have.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <ul>
        <li class="veg">1</li>   
        <li class="veg">1</li>         
        <li class="veg">1</li>            
        <li class="veg">1</li>     
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <ul>
        <li class="veg">1</li>   
        <li class="veg">1</li>            
        <li class="veg">1</li>            
        <li class="veg">1</li>            
        <li class="veg">1</li>            
        <li class="veg">1</li> 
        <li class="veg">1</li>            
        <li class="veg">1</li>            
        <li class="veg">1</li>  
        <li class="veg">1</li>     
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <ul>
        <li class="veg">1</li>   
        <li class="veg">1</li>            
        <li class="veg">1</li>            
        <li class="veg">1</li>            
        <li class="veg">1</li>             
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <ul>
        <li class="veg">1</li>   
        <li class="veg">1</li>             
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <ul>
        <li class="veg">1</li>   
        <li class="veg">1</li>            
        <li class="veg">1</li>            
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <ul>
        <li class="veg">1</li>   
        <li class="veg">1</li>            
        <li class="veg">1</li>            
        <li class="veg">1</li>             
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <ul>
        <li class="veg">1</li>   
        <li class="veg">1</li>            
        <li class="veg">1</li>            
        <li class="veg">1</li>            
        <li class="veg">1</li>            
        <li class="veg">1</li>            
        <li class="veg">1</li>     
        <li class="veg">1</li>            
        <li class="veg">1</li>            
        <li class="veg">1</li>            
        <li class="veg">1</li>            
        <li class="veg">1</li>            
        <li class="veg">1</li>   
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use a masonry plug-in for javascript/jquery - there's lots of them that play nice with bootstrap

Comment: Could you show me an example if possible?

Comment: http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/~hasnan/salvattore/ this shows one example, if you google masonry bootstrap3 you'll get more

Comment: Is the order of your HTML blocks important? This can certainly be done with Bootstrap alone if you're able to restructure the markup.

Comment: Yeah its actually going to be menu on a restaurant website. The content is generated dynamically and the order is important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with bootstrap

you can use absolute positioning to manually palce elements or if the elements are dynamically added you can use any library like:-

Waterfall http://wlog.cn/waterfall/

Masonry http://masonry.desandro.com/